# Possible to set default account in YouTube?

Tags: youtube, google-account

With the recent YouTube change, it have now created a new account to me with my full name, instead of my old account, there I did not use my full name.

I can switch between the accounts in top right corner, but it is annoying having to do so for each login. Google tried for a long time to have YouTube users to use their full name instead of their YouTube name.

**Question**

Does there exist a way to have YouTube always login with old account? E.g. through extensions, GreaseMonkey or anything really?

Answer (score 1):

Since Google made that all their services, including Youtube, use Google accounts for managing their information, users could sign in to one service and jump to another service without having to sign in again. Also, users have the option to sign in to several accounts without signing out of the others accounts in the same browser. For details see [Sign in to multiple accounts at once](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?hl=en)

Other alternatives are to use:

- different browsers for each account,
- different browser profiles for each account

**References**
[Create a new browser profile - Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059)
[Use the Profile Manager to create and remove Firefox profiles - Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)

Answer (score 0):

I believe multiple-logins on YouTube work the same as those with your Google account. Per [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-do-i-change-my-default-account-with-google-multiple-sign-in):

> I guess this means that you must click the sign out link (which will
>   sign out of all your accounts), then sign in to the account you want
>   to be the default one, then sign in to all the other accounts.